# FreeMarker and array how to assign an item to a specific position

Tags: arrays, freemarker

I need to modify an array element given the position in FreeMarker.

```
 var arr = [];
 arr[0] = "Jani";
 arr[1] = "Hege";
 arr[2] = "Stale";
 arr[3] = "Kai Jim";
 arr[4] = "Borge";
```

is possible to do this in freemarker, you can teach me an example

```
<#macro cuenta d > 

<#assign posicion=0> 

<#assign arregloCuenta=[]> 

<#list args.array?split(",") as value> 

<#assign posicion=posicion+1> 

<#if d.properties["bchile:tipodoc"]?exists >

 <#if d.properties["bchile:tipodoc"] == value>

 <#assign arregloCuenta=["juan"]> 

<#assign arregloCuenta= arregloCuenta + ["felipe"]> ${args.array[0]} ${posicion} ${arregloCuenta[1]} </#if> </#if> </#list> </#macro>
```

Comment: teach me an example? This is not your Uni class or freelancer . You'll have to show us what have you tried -1

Comment: I have tried this and various other things which have already removed

Comment: <#macro cuenta d >
<#assign posicion=0>

<#assign arregloCuenta=[]>
<#list args.array?split(",") as value>
 <#assign posicion=posicion+1>
  <#if d.properties["bchile:tipodoc"]?exists >
  <#if d.properties["bchile:tipodoc"] == value>
  
  
  <#assign arregloCuenta=["juan"]>
   <#assign arregloCuenta= arregloCuenta + ["felipe"]>
  ${args.array[0]} ${posicion} ${arregloCuenta[1]}
 
 
  </#if>
  </#if>
 </#list>
</#macro>

Comment: ok could you tell me what exactly you're after? You need an example where you can generate something from array ?

Comment: I need to modify an array element giving the position in freemarker

Answer (score 5):

From FAQ of FreeMarker:

> The FreeMarker Template Language doesn't support the modification of sequences/hashes. It's for displaying already calculated things, not for calculating data. Keep templates simple. But don't give up, you will see some advice and tricks below.

And a little more below:

> For example, you want to display a keyword index on some very smart way, whose algorithm need you to create and write some sequence variables. Then you should do something like this (ugly situations has ugly solutions...):
>
> ```
> <#assign calculatedResults =
> 'com.example.foo.SmartKeywordIndexHelper'?new().calculate(keywords)>
> <#-- some simple algorithms comes here, like: -->
> <ul>
>   <#list calculatedResults as kw>
>     <li><a href="${kw.link}">${kw.word}</a>
>   </#list>
> </ul>
> ```
>
> That is, you move out the complex part of the presentation task from the template into Java code. Note that it doesn't affect the data-model, so the presentation is still kept separated from the other application logic. Of course, the drawback is that for this the template author will need the help of a Java programmer, but for complex algorithms that's probably needed anyway.

Also it said that **is better to try to use sequence concatenation and sequence slice than this trick**.

For slice and concatenation you can think in something like:

```
seq[0..pos-1] + ["New element"] + seq[pos+1..]
```

You can read the complete entry in http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_modify_seq_and_map